# Edit a disabled input field with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a disabled field that I want to edit with the below script

```
<html>
<select id="country"onchange="changeCountryCode()">
<input type="text" disabled id="cc">
<script>
function changeCountryCode()
{
   var temp = $('country').val();
   $('cc').val(temp);
}
</script>
</html>
```

It's not working for me.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: What do you wish to edit? Is using that script a "must" to achieve your objectives?

Comment: It's not working for me...and I did reference jquery

Comment: You are missing `#` in the query.

Comment: What is not working? Be more specific..

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer if it solved your problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have almost works but you are missing the `#` in your selectors. The `#` sign tells jQuery to use the `ID attribute` when looking up the element desired.

Should be:

```
var temp = $('#country').val();
$('#cc').val(temp);
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I just figured that out. That was the problem.

Comment: Can I add an extended question to that?

Comment: If it's closely related, then edit your question and add the updated details; otherwise, make a new question. In either case try to be more specific as to what you want to achieve, and what's not working, and any error details. This helps people not have to guess...